# *SOLVED* Is there a package that allows horizontal spacing according to the space occupied by a sentence?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, packages

Un example of how it would function

Example:

```
Una araña verde
\hspacew{Una araña} azul
```

Out:

```
Una araña verde.
          azul.
```

Comment: What's wrong with `\hphantom{Una araña}`?

Comment: right, i forgot it.. thx

Comment: `\newcommand{\hspacew}{\hphantom}`